# Canvas in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, canvas, horizontalscrollview

I faced with such a problem that Canvas does not paint in HorizontalScrollView. Instead, I get a blank screen. But if we add any other object, then everything is working perfectly.I have someone with that?

Here my Point.class

```
public class Point extends View implements Serializable {

    private float x;
    private float y;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();

    public Point(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);

    }

    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(float x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(float y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawCircle(getX(), getY(), 5f, paint);
    }
}
```

My Field class, where I want to display my points

```
public class GraphicField extends RelativeLayout {

    private RelativeLayout scrollLayout;

    public GraphicField(Context context) {
        super(context);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.graph_field, this);

        scrollLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.scrollLayout);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        Point point = new Point(getContext());
        point.setX(10);
        point.setY(10);
        scrollLayout.addView(point);
        point = new Point(getContext());
        point.setX(200);
        point.setY(200);
        scrollLayout.addView(point);
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftLayout"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/blue_dark" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftLayout"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrollLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@color/blue_dark"
                android:minWidth="1000dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

If I replace HorizontalScrollView to RelativeLayout, then points perfectly displaying. Please help someone

Comment: have you used hierarchyviewer?

Comment: No.I never even heard of it. It can help me?

Comment: even if it does not help, you will know just another nice tool ;-)

Comment: =) yeah, nice tool, but didn't help me.. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be wrong is that your view collpases when placed in ScrollViews.

You'll solve the issue by adding the following attributes to your view's xml line codes :

```
android:minHeight="1000"
android:minWidth="1000"
```

But best solution is to override the 'onMeasure() method of your CustomView class :

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int desiredWidth = 2000;  //enter your width in px
    int desiredHeight = 1000;  //enter your height in px

    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    int width;
    int height;

    if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        width = widthSize;
    } else if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        width = Math.min(desiredWidth, widthSize);
    } else {
        width = desiredWidth;
    }

    if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        height = heightSize;
    } else if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        height = Math.min(desiredHeight, heightSize);
    } else {
        height = desiredHeight;
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```